# Sidebar not scrolling full content

Tags: html, css

I have a layout in which i have header, sidebar  and main section.

I have a fixed sidebar. Inside that  have 35 section. Scroll bar is not covering all content. My scroll bar is visible till 32 section.

I have tried a lot but unable to do. i think problem is with `.sidenav` property `top`

Here is my code
[PenCode](https://codepen.io/dhairya-lakhera/pen/VwaRQeV) Link

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 300px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 50;
      left: 0;
      background-color: white;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .sidenav a {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .main {
      margin-left: 300px;
      /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
      font-size: 28px;
      /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
      padding: 0px 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false
      });

      $( "h3" ).click(function() {
          $('.sidenav').scrollTop(document.getElementById(this.id).offsetTop);
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header" style="min-height:100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3 id="w1">Section 1</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w2">Section 2</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w3">Section 3</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w4">Section 4</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w5">Section 5</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w6">Section 6</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w7">Section 7</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w8">Section 8</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w9">Section 9</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w10">Section 10</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w11">Section 11</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w12">Section 12</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w13">Section 13</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w14">Section 14</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w15">Section 15</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w16">Section 16</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w17">Section 17</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w18">Section 18</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w19">Section 19</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w20">Section 20</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w21">Section 21</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w22">Section 22</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w23">Section 23</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w24">Section 24</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w32">Section 32</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w26">Section 26</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w27">Section 27</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w28">Section 28</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w29">Section 29</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w30">Section 30</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w31">Section 31</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w32">Section 32</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w33">Section 33</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w34">Section 34</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w35">Section 35</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Main Section</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.sidenav`  class replace this

```
height: 100%;
```

with

```
height: calc(100% - 100px);
```

**Hint:** You don't need the `top: 50;` and `left: 0;`.

Comment: any explantion please? what was the problem with 100% and what calc doing?

Comment: @Curious Few things. Your height specification was wrong because you had reserved 100px for your header. So by using calc() this header height was removed. So it actually get the remaining height.

Comment: Also your `top: 50;` is incorrect. Because it was missing the `px`. The correct way to write is `top: 50px`. But whenever the value is `0` you can write it without `px`, `em` or `rem`. But here you don't need `left:` and `top:`. Glad to help ;)

Comment: i have another problem. till section 21 my accordion working fine. when i click on any section its move to the top. but after 21 section its not moving to top. I think it also problem related to height. you fix and suggestion will be valuable

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `height: calc(100% - 100px);` in your `sidenav` class. your `sidenav` was fixed, but you have a `header` which height is `100px`, but you added style to your `HTML` and `body` that you have 100% height, that's why the sidenav was not covering fully because of the header have 100px

```js
    $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false
      });
    });
```

```css
html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .sidenav {
      height: calc(100% - 100px);
      width: 300px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 50;
      left: 0;
      background-color: white;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .sidenav a {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .main {
      margin-left: 300px;
      /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
      font-size: 28px;
      /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
      padding: 0px 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <div class="header" style="min-height:100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3 id="w1">Section 1</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w2">Section 2</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w3">Section 3</h3>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w4">Section 4</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w5">Section 5</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w6">Section 6</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w7">Section 7</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w8">Section 8</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w9">Section 9</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w10">Section 10</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w11">Section 11</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w12">Section 12</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w13">Section 13</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w14">Section 14</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w15">Section 15</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w16">Section 16</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w17">Section 17</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w18">Section 18</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w19">Section 19</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w20">Section 20</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w21">Section 21</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w22">Section 22</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w23">Section 23</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w24">Section 24</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w32">Section 32</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w26">Section 26</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w27">Section 27</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w28">Section 28</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w29">Section 29</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w30">Section 30</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w31">Section 31</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w32">Section 32</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w33">Section 33</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w34">Section 34</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="w35">Section 35</h3>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Main Section</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have another problem. till section 21 my accordion working fine. when i click on any section its move to the top. but after 21 section its not moving to top. I think it also problem related to height. you fix and suggestion will be valuable